# Android AVD Keeps Terminating

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I am learning to develop Android apps with Java. I have recently installed Android studio and I am familiarizing myself with the software. I have installed the Android 11 and 12 SDKs and the correct SDK tools. I have created 2 AVDs (Pixel 5 and Pixel C), both with Android 11.

I created an empty activity for a Hello World app. I tried to run the Pixel 5 emulator, but it didn't load fully and displayed the message "The emulator process for AVD Pixel 5 Android 11 has terminated".

I repeatedly tried to load it but the same thing kept happening. I tried with the Pixel C but the same thing happened again. Does anyone know how to fix this or why it is happening?